# What is the name of this curve?

Tags: geometry

When I was a kid I used to draw this shape below but today I came against it as a problem. I don't know the name of this red curve below.  It is enough to say the name if it is a known curve. I will search for it's properties.
[image]

The shape is constructed with lines from point $(0,n)$ to $(8-(n-1),0)$ and the curves passes through the intersection of each two lines. In contrast to the figure, the red curve never crosses the axes. $n=0,1,...,9$ however the shape does not need to be discrete, hence $n$ can go to $0$. Probably the values on the axes are not important to know the name of the curve.

Comment: Curve stitching, (quadratic) Bézier curve

Comment: @peterwhy thanks

Comment: It looks to be a branch of a [hyperbola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola), but I'm not sure.

Comment: @CameronBuie No, when you take continuous $n$ the curve will ends at $(0,9)$ and $(9,0)$.

Comment: Upvote if you made this with string and pins. :)

Comment: @Kaz it is not difficult. Start from $8$ turn around $1$ then go to $7$ turn around go to $2$ ...

Comment: You also might be interested in a [tractrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractrix) (which is not the same thing)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The particular curve suggested, tangent to all of the segments from $(0,a)$ to $(9-a,0)$ as $a$ runs from $0$ to $9$, is this one:
$$
y = x-6\sqrt{x}+9
$$

This is a portion of a parabola, with axis on the $x=y$ line and vertex at $(9/4,9/4)$.

To see this more clearly, add also such lines with $a>9$ and $a<0$ ...

[image]

Answer (score 11):

For this particular example, the red curve is "stitched" by a family of straight lines of
$$\begin{align*}
\frac x{9-k} + \frac yk =& 1\\
y =& k - \frac{kx}{9-k}
\end{align*}$$
where $0<k<9$.

When there are two such straight lines with parameters $h$ and $k$ respectively, $h\ne k$,
$$\begin{align*}
y =& h - \frac{hx}{9-h}\\
y =& k - \frac{kx}{9-k}\\
\end{align*}$$

Their intersection can be calculated as
$$\begin{align*}
h - \frac{hx}{9-h} =& k - \frac{kx}{9-k}\\
\frac{kx}{9-k} - \frac{hx}{9-h} =& k - h\\
x\cdot\frac{9k-hk-9h+kh}{(9-k)(9-h)} =& k - h\\
x =& \frac{(9-k)(9-h)}9\\
\end{align*}$$

When we take $h\to k$, the $x$-coordinates becomes
$$x = \frac{(9-k)^2}9$$

and the $y$-coordinates is
$$y = k - \frac{kx}{9-k} = k - \frac{k(9-k)}{9} = \frac{k^2}9$$

We can get an implicit curve for our range
$$\sqrt x + \sqrt y = 3$$

Answer (score 5):

It's a quadratic [Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

Comment: It's a quadratic Bezier segment, with control points (0, 9), (0, 0), and (9, 0), I believe. That means that you can write it as
$t^2 (9, 0) + 2t*(t-1) * (0, 0) + (1-t)^2 *(0, 9)$, which simplifies to $(9 t^2, 9(1-t)^2)$. Just in case you have access to matlab, here's code to make the picture:

   t = linspace(0, 1, 200);
   x = 9 * t.^2;
   y = 9 * (1-t).^2;

   plot(x, y);
   hold on;
   % draw the lines
   for i = 0:9
       plot( [0, 9-i], [i, 0], 'r');
   end
   set(gca, 'DataAspectRatio', [1 1 1]);
   hold off;
   figure(gcf);

Comment: @John thank you very much, your comment is very useful.

Comment: This is a good (best?) answer because it directly addresses the construction of the curve from line segments.  This process is [De Casteljau's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm#Geometric_interpretation).

Answer (score 5):

It's a (portion of a) parabola.

By the curve-stitching construction, it's what's called an ["envelope"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_%28mathematics%29) of the family of line segments. The Wikipedia article (starting at "For example, let $C_t$ be the lines whose $x$ and $y$ intercepts are $t$ and $1-t$...") walks somewhat quickly through your problem as its example (except with $x$ and $y$ intercepts of $1$ instead of $9$).

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578662/what-is-this-beauty-curve), we are most probably dealing with a [superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse), a geometric shape described by algebraic equations of the form $x^n+y^n=r^n$, perhaps with $n=\frac12$ or $\frac23$ ([astroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid)) , or maybe some other form of [hypocycloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocycloid). Their bidimensional generalizations are called [superformulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superformula), and their three-dimensional counterparts are known as [superellipsoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipsoid), [superquadrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superquadrics) or [supereggs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superegg). The case $n=4$ is called a [squircle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This curve is a rotated parabola. As drawn in the picture, you get a parametric curve with: $$x = \frac{(t-7)(t-8)}{9}, y = \frac{(t+1)(t+2)}{9}$$ Applying a $45$° rotation counterclockwise, you get:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x' \\
y' \end{array} \right) =
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\sin(45) & -\cos(45) \\
\cos(45) & \sin(45) \end{array} \right) \times
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x \\
y \end{array} \right)$$

Plugging the parametrized forms of $x$ and $y$, you can see, by direct check, that:

$$ y' = \frac{\sqrt{2}(x')^2}{162}+20\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Though probably not equivalent, it is similar to a hyperbola in the first quadrant. Try graphing points for the equation $y = \dfrac{1}{x}$ to see a basic example. Changing the value in the numerator above $x$ is what dictates how far away the whole curve is from at the origin at its closest point (which is on the line $x=y$). Also, a numerator that is an integer with several divisors will also have several integer solutions for $(x,y)$.

Example: Graph the equation $y=\dfrac{20}{x}$ and see how it has integer solutions at (1,20), (2,10), (4,5), (5,4), (10,2), and (20,1).

Comment: That was my first thought too. But the other answers convinced me that it's a parabola.